# How to perform a map using reduce

Tags: clojure

Hello I have a simple function like this:

```
(def state
  (memoize
    (fn state [t]
      (if (<= t 0)
        0
        1))))
```

on which I am trying to call `(reduce state (range 10))` which the intent of calling the function `state` on the range `0 1 2 3 4 5 ...`, and receiving back `0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1`.

That is not happening, thus I am obviously misunderstanding something, since I am getting:

```
clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (2) passed to: state
```

The syntax for reduce is `(reduce f coll)` and my understanding was that it is as simple as doing `(reduce + [1 2 3 4 5])`.

Obviously one can do this easily enough with `map` I was just under the impression that `reduce` would work as well. With map, `(map (fn [x] (state x)) (range 10))`.

PS. this is just a test case, I genuinely do need `memoization` for the real thing.

Thanks

Comment: `reduce` will give you just one "answer."  if you want a list like that, you will need `map`.  Make your `def` a `defn` and you should be on your way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Obviously one can do this easily enough with map I was just under the impression that reduce would work as well.

Yes. Any `map` can also be a `reduce`. (Except reduce is not lazy, while map is).

The result of a reduce function is going to be the result that is returned in the end after N iterations of your function over your reduction range.

Your function returns a 0 or a 1, therefore, your reduce will ultimately return either a 0 or 1.

If you want to return a list, then your reduction function needs to return a list. Or, use a function other than reduce, such as map.

Also -- all reduction functions take 2 arguments, not 1. So your `state` function is not a valid function to pass to reduce. Though, it is a valid function to pass to map.

Incidentally, you *can* do this with reduce, you don't *need* map -- in fact, many functions can be expressed as reduce, including map, filter and others. But, you'd need to alter your reduction function to make it compatible.

The comments and other answers suggest you must use map, but here is a reduce that will do it:

```
(def state
     (memoize
       (fn state [r t]
         (if (<= t 0)
             (conj r 0)
             (conj r 1)))))

(reduce state [] (range 10))

;;-> [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
```

This is a great idiom when you have logic for the value of a particular item that depends on knowing about the other items. You do not have such logic here, so map is a better choice. But conceptually you can express many things in functional programming in terms of a `fold` which is what `reduce` is.

Here is an alternate method, keeping the original `state` function from the question, and therefore its memoization intact:

```
(def state
  (memoize
    (fn state [t]
      (if (<= t 0)
        0
        1))))

(defn r-fn [r t]
   (conj r (state t)))

(reduce r-fn [] (range 10))

;;-> [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
```

This is more succinctly written as:

`(reduce #(conj %1 (state %2)) [] (range 10))`

Comment: wouldn't that render the `memoize` useless, since the `r` is ever growing (asuming, that `range` here is just for examples sake and the real sequence there will have many duplicates)?

Answer (score 2):

well, that's because the reduce function should take exactly 2 parameters: accumulator and item from the coll, bur in case the accumulator is not provided during `reduce` call, the first step of reduction is applied to first 2 values from coll:

`(reduce + '(1 2 3 4))` is really `(+ (+ (+ 1 2) 3) 4)`

but that's not what you need in your case:

```
user> (map state (range 10))
(0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1)
```

as you don't want to **reduce** a coll to a single value, but rather **map** each value to another

Comment: The issue about not getting a list as a reduce result is less about the arguments that a reduce function accepts, and instead about the value a reduce function returns.

Comment: Or use `reductions` with proper `reduce` parameters.